# How to find Mongoose documents where subdocument values are equal

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model with subdocuments as below. How can I find all Cars that have "registered" drivers over the age of 25?

```
const CarSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  brand: {
    type: String
  },
  year: {
    type: Number
  },
  drivers: {
    type: [DriversSchema]
  }
})

const DriverSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  age: {
    type: String
  },
  registered: {
    type: Boolean
  }
})
```

This is what I've tried:

```
Car.find({
  'drivers.age': {$gt: 25},
  'drivers.registered': true
})
```

However this returns all Cars that have drivers over 25 and drivers that are registered, but not the desired outcome, which is only returning Cars that have drivers that meet both of those requirements.

For example, it should not return the Car that has one non-registered driver over 25, and one registered driver under 25.

How to achieve this?

Comment: use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator to match all fields in single element.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! @t

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the cars where all the drivers `age>=25` AND `registered=true` you can do it like bellow with aggregation pipeline.

Finds the illegal-drivers with filter, and then reject car-document that had not empty illegal-drivers.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t80i45FiS7h)

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [
      {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$drivers",
            "as": "driver",
            "cond": {
              "$or": [
                {
                  "$lt": [
                    "$$driver.age",
                    25
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$not": [
                    "$$driver.registered"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      0
    ]
  }
})
```